# Select2 is not selected when update a select field by ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing a problem when I use `select2` class in select option. When I insert a form data using a field `select2` class by ajax call then it is working properly

But when I update that `select2` field by ajax calling same form firstly it is not selected value that I inserted first.

**Note**

ajax response is working properly

**cdn, css and javascript integrated properly**

I have tried below

**Input Field**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Status:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="form-control select2" name="status_user" id="status_user" style="width:100%;">
            <option value="">-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Active</option>
            <option value="0">Inactive</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('.select2').select2()

} );
```

**Ajax Update**

```
$('#status_user').val('');

$.ajax({

        type:"post",

        url:"./cc/xyz.php",

        data: {
            row_id:                 action_id,
            conditional_value:      14
        },

        success:function(response){

            var responseData =  JSON.parse(response);
            $('#status_user').val(responseData.status_user);
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: You  need use [$('#status_user').trigger("change")](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options) .

Comment: @Swati it is not working

Comment: what does `responseData.status_user` giving you ?

Comment: @Swati it gives me `0` or `1`

Comment: Not sure what might be wrong because you said ajax is working and its giving you `0 1` . But , just to make sure where you have put that line which i told you in my previous comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same problem few days ago. I have solved this issue from [Select2 Documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options)

```
$('#status_user').val('');
```

Replace by this

```
var statusSelect = $('#status_user');
```

And in your ajax request add new line

```
$('#status_user').val(responseData.status_user);
statusSelect.append(responseData.status_user).trigger('change'); // Add this line
```