# Laravel Dusk and Select2

Tags: laravel, testing, jquery-select2

I'm working with Laravel 8 and for the screen tests I'm using Dusk (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk).

In one of the screens, i have a select2 with "tags" property enabled (https://select2.org/tagging), that allows you to create a new record if there is no option in select.

I just cant the test "Create a new option for select2 with dusk" work for some reason

I've tried using this package (https://github.com/roquie/laravel-dusk-select2) and also using scripts (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#executing-javascript) to get this result, but in none of the cases successful.

```
Blade

<select 
    class="select2" 
    name="nome" 
    required
>
    <option value="1">Teste 1</option>
    <option value="2">Teste 2</option>
</select>

Js

$('.select2').select2({ 
    tags: true,
});
```

Comment: Two item selected at. a time?? Is it possible in `select2`?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. Now it's right. But, it is possible. https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes

Comment: If you don't mind I suggest you to use this https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following code

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('.select2').select2()

} );
```

You may see this [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600924/select2-is-not-selected-when-update-a-select-field-by-ajax-call/66602764#66602764)

Answer (score -2):

Try following code in your testing file.

> $browser->select2('select[name= nome]', 'Teste 1')

Not necessary to use 'laravel-dusk-select2'