# Display the value of a dependent select box using laravel / ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to edit data , So I display the data in a form to update it.

So I have the following code:

```js
<!-- Script fot getting the sstates of a country-->


  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#pays").change(function() {
      /* let country_id = this.value;*/
      let country_id = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
      $.get('/getState/' + country_id, function(data) {
        $("#ville").html(data);
      });
    });
  });

<!-- Script for edit data-->

$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {

  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
  $('#form_result').html('');

  $.ajax({

    url: "castingss/" + id + "/edit",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(html) {
      console.log(html);

      $('#pays').val(html.data.pays);
      $('#pays').trigger('change');
      $('#ville').val(html.data.ville);
      $("#ville").trigger('change');


    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Pays</label>
    <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="pays" id="pays">
      <option label="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
      @foreach($countries as $country)
      <option data-id="{{$country->id}}" value="{{$country->name}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Ville</label>
    <select class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%" name="ville" id="ville">

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I get the following result:

[image]

Only the value of the `pays` is `selected` , but the value of the `ville` is not selected .

When I did `console.log(html)` , I'm getting succefully the value of the ville but is not diplayed on the form.

What is wrong with my code , if you have any idea please help.

**EDIT**

```
Console.log(html)

{data: {…}}
  data: 
    pays: "Algeria",
    ville: "Adrar"
      [[Prototype]]: Object[[Prototype]]: Object
```

**Controller**

```
public function getAllStates()

    {
        $country_id = request('country');

        $states = State::where('country_id',$country_id)->get();

       /* dd($states);*/
    
        $option = "<option value = ''> Select State</option>";


        foreach($states as $state){
            $option.= '<option value = "'.$state->name.'">'.$state->name.'</option>';
        }
        return $option;
    }
```

Comment: Share your output `console.log(html);`

Comment: @A.ANoman , check my Edit

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. I use like below

```
var villeTag = $('#ville');

$('#ville').val(html.data.ville);
villeTag.append(html.data.ville).trigger('change');
```

[Please Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600924/select2-is-not-selected-when-update-a-select-field-by-ajax-call/66602764#66602764)

Comment: thank you for your answer , I tried it but doesn't work

Comment: I did that : `$('#pays').val(html.data.pays);
             $('#pays').trigger('change'); 
             $('#ville').val('');
             var villeTag = $('#ville');
             $('#ville').val(html.data.ville);
             villeTag.append(html.data.ville).trigger('change'); ` but doesn't work

Comment: You may try first `<select class="form-control" data-width="100%" name="ville" id="ville">` then check is it working?

Comment: I get only `Select State`

Comment: please check my controller

Comment: it works when I delete this script : `$(document).ready(function(){$("#pays").change(function() {
      let country_id = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
      $.get('/getState/' + country_id, function(data) {
        $("#ville").html(data);
      });
    });
  });`

Comment: @saadia, Do you add two `select option` `#ville` at same time

Comment: What do u mean ?

Comment: @saadia, Nothing to say, If your problem is solved then it will be better

Comment: No it doesn't , I delete the script which get dynamically the states of a country , I shouldn't delete it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235783/discussion-between-a-a-noman-and-saadia).